# Closing a doc file after converting it to pdf

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am converting a doc file to a pdf file but with my current code it seems that the file is open even after the conversion. I see the pdf file in the output folder but if i try to reupload it tells me that it is opened in another program(which i don't see anywhere).

Code section error:

```
if (getExt == ".doc")
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(DocumentUNCPath.Text);

    wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(@"c:\temp\DocTo.pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
}
```

**The full method:**

```
private void btnSubmitStep2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string getExt = Path.GetExtension(DocumentUNCPath.Text);
    if (getExt == ".doc")
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(DocumentUNCPath.Text);

        wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(@"c:\temp\DocTo.pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
    }

    // Frame up the record of submission
    using (var dc = new DocMgmtDataContext())
    {
        DocumentLibrary.Document doc = new DocumentLibrary.Document()
        {
            LibraryID = (AssignmentListStep2.SelectedItem as Library).ID,
            OwnedByUserID = (StudentListStep2.SelectedItem as User).ID,
            UploadedByUserID = (StudentListStep2.SelectedItem as User).ID,
            UploadDT = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ID = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        dc.Documents.InsertOnSubmit(doc);
        dc.SubmitChanges();

        // Copy file into managed storage
        doc.StoragePath = FILESTORELOCATION + doc.ID + ".pdf";
        File.Copy(DocumentUNCPath.Text, doc.StoragePath);

        doc.Pages = CompatiblePdfReader.VerifyAndFixPdfDocument(doc.StoragePath);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }

    // Refresh the list of student submissions
    UpdateStudentSubmissionGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing the document at the end of your sub with `wordDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges`, as `ExportAsFixedFormat` doesn't close the file for you.

Comment: thanks i will go ahead and try this. but to i enter ur suggestion in the clause where i check the extension or before the statement of `UpdateStudentSubmissionGrid();`?

Comment: At the first point where you are no longer using the word document. I would suggest just after the ExportAsFixedFormat call. `wordDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges`